# RPi4 support - raspi-config and gpio?

Tags: raspberrypi, mongodb, arm64

I want to know if there will be official support for things like raspi-config and gpio on the official ubuntu releases for the Raspberry Pi 4?

I was initially drawn to it for the 64-bit capabilities and due to the lack of package support on Raspbian, For eg mongoDB, where the latest compatible version is the long deprecated v2.4. However since I am using this in an embedded system, I do need both the 64-bit capabilities as well as being able to interact with gpio pins and peripheral interfaces such as i2c and spi.

There are unofficial and custom images that support this, but I don't think these are appropriate when deving with the intent of moving to production. So, coudld this be a possibility?

Comment: Would you have any update on this topic?

Answer (score 2):

I'm running it on both of my PI 4s and my PI 3. I use I2C, Serial and over 20 different GPIO pins on one of my PI 4s. So to partly answer your question, yes you can do all of those things out of the box on arm64 Ubuntu.

Note: I use .Net Core 3.x to do all of my coding. No issues so far.

Comment: And you are running Ubuntu 20.04? Could you please explain some of the steps you took to achieve this? I am trying to interface with an ADC, namely the ADS1115